# Javascript, SAVE current URL to file & add extra code to the saved file

Tags: javascript

This script works to save the current URL to a file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("create(window.location.href, 'file.html', 'text/plain')");
function create(text, name, type) {
  var dlbtn = document.getElementById("save");
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  save.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  save.download = name;
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="save"><button>SAVE</button></a>
```

But I need the finished file to look like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "CURRENT URL GOES HERE";
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple template literal does the trick. I also changed the `setTimeout()` to be a callback instead of a string, and to have a delay of 0 instead of an implied 0. Another thing I changed was the type from `text/plain` to `text/html`.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout(() => create('file.html', 'text/html'), 0); // type needs to be text/html to save as an HTML file and not a txt file
  function create(name, type) {
    var dlbtn = document.getElementById("save");
    // Template literal
    const text = `<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "${window.location.href}";
</scri${"pt"}>` // Have to do the ${"pt"} to fix HTML wanting to close the script tag
    var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
    dlbtn.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    dlbtn.download = name;
  }
</script>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="save"><button>SAVE</button></a>
```